# In Aurelia, can we set the value of a custom control attribute in its sub-element like in XAML?

Tags: aurelia

Suppose I have an Aurelia custom control 'my-control' with an attribute 'my-attribute', is it possible to do something similar to this.

```
<my-control>
    <my-control.my-attribute>
        <div>hello</div>
    </my-control.my-attribute>
</my-control>
```

Comment: the correct syntax in aurelia would be `<my-control my-attribute.bund="myValue"></my-control>` (supposing this attribute is marques a bindable). also: take a look at `slot` api - it's looking like what you need.

Comment: thanks Avrahamcool, I know that syntax but I would like to know if it is possible to write it in the other way so that we don't have to put <div>hello</div> within the double quote.

Comment: yes.. you can do it using the [slot api](https://aurelia.io/docs/templating/content-projection#basic-content-projection).